# How to calculate using a for-loop with odd numbers and print only average

Tags: powershell, for-loop

**Problem:** **Using a for loop, compute the average of the first 20 odd numbers. Print only the average.**

I have figured out how to count the first 20 odd numbers in the for loop but I can't figure out how to get the average where it only prints the average. Right now it is printing the total of all the odd numbers of 400.

Any help would be greatly appreciative. Also, if you could explain in simple terms as I am a beginner.

```
{
$avg=0
    for ($i =1 ; $i –le 39 ; $i+=2) {
    $avg = $avg +$i 
}
echo $avg
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average (or arithmetic mean) is defined as the sum of the data divided by the number of items in the data set.

therefore you must divide the final sum of odd numbers by two.

```
$sum=0

for ($i =1 ; $i –lt 20 ; $i+=2) {
    $sum = $sum + $i 
}

$avg = $sum / 20

echo $avg
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement [henry groves' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73260076/45375):

The [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) cmdlet has an `-Average` switch that automatically calculates the average of all numbers it receives via the pipeline and reports it in the `.Average` property of the [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo) instance it outputs:

```bash
(
  & { for ($i =1 ; $i –le 39 ; $i+=2) { $i } } | Measure-Object -Average
).Average
```

This outputs `20`. (To assign the result to variable `$avg`, simply prepend `$avg =`  to the entire command.)

Note that `for`, as a language statement, cannot directly participate in a pipeline, hence its invocation via a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) called with [`&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).

---

As an aside:

For looping over a range of integers with an *increment of `1`* (or `-1`), PowerShell offers `..`, the convenient [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-); e.g. `1..3` is effectively the same as 
`for ($i=1; $i -le 3; ++$i) { $i }`; `3..1` works analogously.

It would be great if `..` also supported *specifiable* increments (*stepping*), such as `2` in your case, which isn't supported as of PowerShell 7.2.x.

[GitHub issue #7928](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7928) proposes adding such support in the future, which *could* take the following form.

```bash
# WISHFUL THINKING as of PowerShell 7.2.x
# If implemented, would be the equivalent of:
#   for ($i =1 ; $i –le 39 ; $i += 2) { $i }
1..39..2
```

Comment: Just for fun, two pure pipeline solutions: `1..39 | Where-Object { $_ % 2 } | Measure-Object -Average | ForEach-Object Average` and `0..19 | ForEach-Object { 1 + $_ * 2 } | Measure-Object -Average | ForEach-Object Average`

Answer (score 1):

While there are many correct ways to solve a problem, let me give you a recommendation on your loop: As your task basically just consists of having 20 iterations, you should use a more readable and intuitive way to describe 20 iterations. Your loop could look like this, for example:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 20; $i++) {
    $sum += 2 * $i + 1
}
$avg = $sum / 20
echo $avg
```

In programming/scripting you will encounter, that you most often start counting/indexing at 0. So my recommendation is: Get used to it, don't start at 1, if it is not necessary. Secondly, I define my iteration with default step size 1 and a break condition of `$i -lt 20`, which clearly contains 20, which we already know from your task. I could achieve the same result with `$i -le 19`, but then I would loose the direct relation to your task again.

Don't get me wrong, `($i =1 ; $i –le 39 ; $i+=2)` is absolutely correct and deterministic with no randomness involved, but it is a little harder to understand than `($i = 0; $i -lt 20; $i++)`, for example.

You might ask now, why am I telling you all this? Well, there is the quite popular [*off-by-one error*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). And with your technique, you will sooner or later become a victim of this error. Maybe you already did while trying to develop your loop condition.

Comment: Thanks for explaining another way of writing the script.  For whatever reason I just understood it the way I did but this stuff is so new to me that I kind of ran with what I got to work and understood.  When we do our final timed exam this month we have to write scripts and explain each line of code.  So, I am going add your script to my study notes as that is probably best practice to count/index starting at 0 like you said.  Appreciate the help!